# Prometheus less than max value expression

Tags: prometheus

We are storing the software version for our applications in a Prometheus gauge called `app_software_version`, which results in data that looks like this:

```
app_software_version{application="foo", instance="host-1", job="custom"}     3186
app_software_version{application="foo", instance="host-2", job="custom"}     3184
app_software_version{application="bar", instance="host-3", job="custom"}     279
app_software_version{application="bar", instance="host-4", job="custom"}     279
```

We want to create a PromQL expression which returns True for instances where the version of the application is less than the max version we have stored for that application, telling us the instance this is true for. The use-case for this: We want the expression to drive an alert rule that tells us if we have one of our instances running an old version of a piece of software.

In the example above, we would like an expression which, when evaluated, returns something like this

```
{application="foo", instance="host-2}    True
```

We have been able to create an expression which calculates the maximum software version for each application, by running `max(app_software_version) by(application)` we get

```
{application="foo"}    3186
{application="bar"}    279
```

Unfortunately, we have not been able to successfully build this into an expression which gives the result we are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
app_software_version < on(application) group_left max(app_software_version) by(application)
```

It uses [many-to-one join](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches) for comparing every series on the left side to the max value per `application` label on the right side.